# CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS raises duplicate key error

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, ddl, catalog

To give some context, the command is issued inside a task, and many task might issue the same command from multiple workers at the same time.

Each tasks tries to create a postgres schema. I often get the following error:

> ```
> IntegrityError: (IntegrityError) duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_namespace_nspname_index"
> DETAIL:  Key (nspname)=(9621584361) already exists.
>  'CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS "9621584361"'
> ```

Postgres version is PostgreSQL 9.4rc1.
Is it a bug in Postgres?

Comment: It looks like the IF EXISTS works only after the commit, not during your transactions that have not yet been committed.

Comment: `CREATE SCHEMA` has the `IF NOT EXISTS` clause since Postgres 9.3, so I don't expect your version 9.4rc1 has anything to do with it. But you should still [upgrade to the latest stable release, currently 9.4.1](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a bit of a wart in the implementation of `IF NOT EXISTS` for tables and schemas. Basically, they're an upsert attempt, and PostgreSQL doesn't handle the race conditions cleanly. It's safe, but ugly.

If the schema is being concurrently created in another session but isn't yet committed, then it both exists and does not exist, depending on who you are and how you look. It's not possible for other transactions to "see" the new schema in the system catalogs because it's uncommitted, so it's entry in `pg_namespace` is not visible to other transactions. So `CREATE SCHEMA` / `CREATE TABLE` tries to create it because, as far as it's concerned, the object doesn't exist.

However, that inserts a row into a table with a unique constraint. Unique constraints must be able to see uncommitted rows in order to function. So the insert blocks (stops) until the first transaction that did the `CREATE` either commits or rolls back. If it commits, the second transaction aborts, because it tried to insert a row that violates a unique constraint. `CREATE SCHEMA` isn't smart enough to catch this case and re-try.

To properly fix this PostgreSQL would probably need predicate locking, where it could lock the *potential for a row*. This might get added as part of the current work going on for implementing `UPSERT`.

For these particular commands, PostgreSQL could probably do a *dirty read* of the system catalogs, where it can see uncommitted changes. Then it could wait for the uncommitted transaction to commit or roll back, re-do the dirty read to see if someone else is waiting, and retry. But this would have a race condition where someone else might create the schema between when you do the read to check for it and when you try to create it.

So the `IF NOT EXISTS` variants would have to:

- Check to see if the schema exists; if it does, finish without doing anything.
- Attempt to create the table
- If creation fails due to a unique constraint error, retry at the start
- If table creation succeeds, finish

As far as I know nobody's implemented that, or they tried and it wasn't accepted. There would be possible issues with transaction ID burn rate, etc, with this approach.

I think this is a bug of sorts, but it's a "yeah, we know" kind of bug, not a "we'll get right on fixing that" kind of bug. Feel free to post to pgsql-bugs about it; at the very least the documentation should mention this caveat about `IF NOT EXISTS`.

I don't recommend doing DDL concurrently like that.

Comment: this doesn't just happen concurrently.  I use mocha which does not run tests concurrently.

Comment: @PositiveGuy Then it's probably a bug. If you can reproduce it into a simple repeatable test case please report it to the mailing list.

Comment: I couldn't find a submission for `CREATE SCHEMA` specifically, but there is a similar bug for `CREATE TABLE` that's been known since 2007: https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/200710222037.l9MKbCJZ098744%40wwwmaster.postgresql.org

Answer (score 4):

I needed to work around this limitation in an application where schemas are created concurrently. What worked for me was adding

```
LOCK TABLE pg_catalog.pg_namespace
```

in the transaction including `CREATE SCHEMA`. Looks like a dirty and unsafe thing to do, but helped me to solve the problem which occurred only in tests anyway.

Comment: Nice, but my user has no permissions to lock `pg_catalog.pg_namespace` what else could I lock before the schema exists?

Comment: I would do `LOCK TABLE pg_catalog.pg_namespace IN SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;` as that's the recommended locking mode for preventing concurrent data changes without blocking reads, whereas `LOCK TABLE` does `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` (excludes all other locks) by default: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html

Comment: @Tarion you could use an advisory lock instead, it doesn't guarantee you won't trigger this error but if the concurrent changes are coming from your code anyway, it should be sufficient: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ADVISORY-LOCKS

Answer (score 1):

Kind of an old topic, but here's a more practical solution than locking the `pg_catalog.pg_namespace` table.

Suppose, like OP, you have tasks that run concurrently but share the same source code. To fix the above race condition, you **need to group your DDLs (e.g. `CREATE SCHEMA`) together inside one transaction**, and then acquire an advisory lock at the transaction level.

This can be done like so:

```sql
SELECT pg_advisory_xact_lock(bigint on 8 bytes at most);
```

This lock will either wait if it's been taken, or proceed directly if it's free. However, the bigint lock id has to be **exactly the same** across all the tasks that experience a race condition. This is a great solution if you know which part of the codebase causes this issue.

I'd recommend using a clear string as the lock_id (such as `"lock for schema ddl"`), and then hashing it into a bigint. That way it's less likely that this arbitrary value's meaning will be forgotten later.

In Python, through SQLAlchemy this would look like this:

```py
import hashlib

def get_transaction_lock(conn: Connection, lock_id: str, timeout_sec: Optional[int] = 300):
    if timeout_sec is not None:
        conn.execute(text(f"SET LOCAL lock_timeout = '{abs(timeout_sec)}s';"))

    # Lock ID has to be a bigint, meaning on 8 bytes
    # hashlib is necessary to obtain a consistent hash, don't use python's hash() func
    num_lock_id = int(hashlib.sha1(lock_id.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest(), 16) % (2 ** 64)
    conn.execute(text(f"SELECT pg_advisory_xact_lock({num_lock_id});"))
```