# concurrent "create table if not exists" fail in postgres with "sequence already exists" error

Tags: postgresql, ddl

We have a microservice-based system where each microservice is in charge of creating and upgrading its schema at startup. All of them use a Postgres 11 DB.

Essentially, each service executes a simple script at startup; for example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS SERVICE_TABLE (
    ID bigserial primary key,
    DATA JSONB
)
```

The problem is that, when a service is deployed with a replication factor higher than 1, so more instances are started at the same time, for example in kubernates, we often see this kind of error in the logs:

> error code 23505  duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "pg_type_typname_nsp_index" detail: (SERVICE_TABLE_id_seq, 2200)
>   already exists

The scripts are executed into a transaction.

It seems that Postgres correctly handles the creation of the table itself only once, but it somehow triggers the creation of the related sequence even when it should not.

Are we missing something? Is this a Postgres bug/limitation?

Comment: The CAPS and mixed-cased identifiers are suspect.

Comment: Maybe it is the same problem as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29900845/create-schema-if-not-exists-raises-duplicate-key-error